# Prove that every set and subset with the cofinite topology is compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

**Prove that every set with the cofinite topology is compact as well as every subset**

Solution. Let $X$ be a nonempty set with the cofinite topology and let $ \mathscr{U}$ be an open cover of $ X $. Let $ U \in \mathscr{U}$. Then $X\setminus U$ is finite. For every $a \in X\setminus U$ let $U_a$ be an element of $\mathscr{U}$ that contains $a$. Then $\{U\}\cup\{U_a : a ∈ X\setminus U\}$
is a finite subcover of $\mathscr{U}$.

**Now I missing the part for  the subsets $E\subseteq X$**. I don't think this refers to the relative topology, but just to any subset of $X$
**How do I go about it?**

Comment: It of course refers to the rel topology and the proof is the same.

Comment: I thought the statement meant that any subset of X was compact with the original topology, not with the relative one

Comment: Well what does it mean to be compact with the original topology?

Comment: @Severin Schraven That you can extract a finite subcover from a open cover made of open sets of the original topology, ( not made of the intersection of them with the set, like in the relative topology.) The reason I make a difference is because  set that is not open in the original topology may be open in the relative. like for example in [-1,1] with the usual topology $\tau$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R} $ . $   E=[-1,1 ]$ is not open in $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ but it is in $(\mathbb{R},\tau_E)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of compactness it makes no difference whether you use the topology of $X$ or the relative topology on the subset.

**Proposition.** Let $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ be any space, let $K\subseteq X$, and let $\tau_K$ be the relative topology on $K$; then $K$ is compact with respect to $\tau$ iff it is compact with respect to $\tau_K$.

**Proof.** Suppose first that $K$ is compact with respect to $\tau$, and let $\mathscr{U}\subseteq\tau'$ be a $\tau'$-open cover of $K$. For each $U\in\mathscr{U}$ there is a $V_U\in\tau$ such that $U=K\cap V_U$. Let $\mathscr{V}=\{V_U:U\in\mathscr{U}\}$; clearly $\mathscr{V}$ is a $\tau$-open cover of $K$, so it has a finite subcover $\{V_{U_1},\ldots,V_{U_n}\}$. Let $\mathscr{F}=\{U_1,\ldots,U_n\}$; $\mathscr{F}$ is a finite subset of $\mathscr{U}$, and

$$\bigcup\mathscr{F}=\bigcup_{k=1}^nU_k=\bigcup_{k=1}^n(K\cap V_{U_k})=K\cap\bigcup_{k=1}^nU_k=K\;,$$

so $\mathscr{F}$ covers $K$. Thus, $K$ is compact with respect to $\tau'$.

Now suppose that $K$ is compact with respect to $\tau'$, and let $\mathscr{U}\subseteq\tau$ be a $\tau$-open cover of $K$. For each $U\in\mathscr{U}$ let $V_U=K\cap U$, and let $\mathscr{V}=\{V_U:U\in\mathscr{U}\}$. $\mathscr{V}$ is a $\tau'$-open cover of $K$, so it has a finite subcover $\{V_{U_1},\ldots,V_{U_n}\}$. Let $\mathscr{F}=\{U_1,\ldots,U_n\}$; $\mathscr{F}$ is a finite subset of $\mathscr{U}$, and

$$\bigcup\mathscr{F}=\bigcup_{k=1}^nU_k\supseteq\bigcup_{k=1}^n(K\cap U_k)=\bigcup_{k=1}^nV_{U_k}=K\;,$$

so $\mathscr{F}$ covers $K$. Thus, $K$ is compact with respect to $\tau$. $\dashv$

Comment: Initially I thought that they were saying that any subset of $X$ was compact, like for example if $X=\mathbb{R}$ with the cofinite topology, then any subset like $ \{1\}$ $[1,2] ,(1,2),(1,2], (1,+\infty)$ should be compact, that is not true, is it?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO: It *is* true. You essentially proved it in your question.